# libcurl's CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE and PHP's curl_getinfo() for FTP transfers

Tags: php, curl, ftp, libcurl

Is it safe to assume that the value PHP's `curl_getinfo()` returns for array key 'http_code' is the value of libcurl's CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE?

In other words: does the value of `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE` using `curl_getinfo()` in PHP correspond to the value of `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE` using `curl_easy_getinfo()` in libcurl?

And it is therefore also meaningful for FTP transfers?

And the value after an FTP transfer is an [FTP reply code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes)?

Answer (score 4):

The actual constant name is **`CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE`** (not `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE`, which is for `libcurl`). Although there is *HTTP* in the name, you can get FTP response codes there as well:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://user:pass@host.com');
curl_exec($ch);

$response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $response_code; // outputs 226, which means 'Closing data connection'
```

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html says:  CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE
Pass a pointer to a long to receive the last received HTTP or FTP code. This option was known as CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE in libcurl 7.10.7 and earlier. This will be zero if no server response code has been received.

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming you're talking about php-curl because you tagged the post with *php* and also because `curl_easy_getinfo` is from the C library, while `curl_getinfo` is from the PHP extension. CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE doesn't exist in PHP, it's CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE. In any case, I think that answers your question. :)

Comment: the question is also tagged libcurl because it asks about the mapping between PHP's `curl_info()` and libcurl. i will edit the question to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, please note that nowadays:

> CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE - The last response code. As of cURL 7.10.8, this is a legacy alias of CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE

[PHP official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)